# Display div result after ajax form submit

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a form that when gets submitted, the page is reloaded and a div called #message is created and is displayed in the body.  I am trying to ajaxify my form which I did but I am stuck on how to get the message to now display without reload.  Here is my code below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input#submit').on('click', function () {
    $('#form').submit(function() {
      $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
      data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
      type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
      url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
      success: function(response) { // on success..
         alert($('div#message').text()); // Alert the message text..fails
      }
      });
       return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
   }); 
 });
});

<form action="settings.php" method="post" class="standard-form" id="form">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="">
        <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" size="16" value="" class="password-entry" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php _e( 'Update'); ?>" id="submit" class="small button"/>
</form>
```

Update:  This is the new function I am trying, however all that gets alerted is "[Object] [object]"  and no actual text.  I am not sure what that means.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input#submit').on('click', function () {
    $('#form').submit(function() {
      $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
      data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
      type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
      url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
      success: function(data) { // on success..
         alert($('div#message').text(data));
      }
      });
       return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
   }); 
 });
});
```

Comment: What's the content of "response" in your success function? Also, try preventing the default form submission using e.preventDefault(); in the $("#form") submit function.

Comment: What does the html look like? And to help debug: Remove your ajax call for now. Make sure you are preventing the default form submission. When you can click the submit button without a redirection you can add your ajax request back.

Comment: @Jasen  I am not sure if you are thinking if theyre is a problem with redirection.  There is none so I am sorry if that is not clear.  The form does not redirect.  After submit I which to alert the content of a div that would normally be present after form submission without ajax

Comment: @kinduff  I have updated with my form html.  The form is not redirecting.  See my comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("form").on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // to prevent default page reloading
    var dataString = $(this).serialize(); // to get the form data

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "post_process.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data){
            $('form')[0].reset(); // to reset form data
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        alert(data); // This will be called after the ajax executed
    });

});
```

Comment: I tried this and what gets alerted is "[Object] [object]".  Not what the message is supposed to be.  Not sure what that means.

Comment: @LearntoExcel Will you please update your HTML so that I can give you more suitable answer.

Comment: @LearntoExcel I've updated the code, please check it out and let me know the result.

Comment: I had to tweak it a little to alert the specific content I wanted but thank you so much.  I learned a lot from this.

Answer (score 0):

I could have missunderstood what you really want to archive but I hope this is it. Sorry if it's not.

When I want to display something new without reloading I am using the `.append()` function which makes a child to a selected element.

For example if I call a database with `ajax()` and want to display the results in a div I select the div with jquery and append the result to the div in the success function.

```
$('#div').append('<p>Info here</p>')
```

This will make a "p-element" which is a child to the div. And it will show up without reload
More about `.append()` here: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: I think its missing to append the response: `success: function(response) { alert($('div#message').text(response)); }`

Comment: Yes I am familiar with append.  The problem is the div isn't created until after form submission and I am trying to get it shown after the ajax call. @kinduff